# Why the navigation to TwoColumnsMidExpanded does not work?

Tags: sapui5

I have created an app based on [Flexible Column Layout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e762257125b34513b0859faa1610b09e). The landing page looks as follows:

[image]

When the button **Go to master detail** is clicked, then it should route to `/overview` page with TwoColumnsMidExpanded.

The press handler is defined as follows:

```
onPress: function (evt) {
            this.oRouter.navTo("overview", {
                layout: fioriLibrary.LayoutType.TwoColumnsMidExpanded
            });
        }
```

The source can be found on https://github.com/softshipper/fcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing the name of the layout via routing parameters just does this: passes the name of the layout via routing parameters.

you still have to take care of the layout in your applications event handlers for the event `routeMatched`.

Here is a nice working example:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.FlexibleColumnLayout/sample/sap.f.sample.FlexibleColumnLayoutWithFullscreenPage/code/webapp/controller/FlexibleColumnLayout.controller.js

pay attention to `onBeforeRouteMatched` handler in `FlexibleColumnLayout.controller.js` on how to deal with that.