# Why it does not show two columns?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use [Flexible Column Layout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e762257125b34513b0859faa1610b09e) on my app and I have trouble with the routing. However it does not show the expected result on the screen.

The routing is defined as follows:

```
"routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.f.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "async": true,
            "viewPath": "com.example.RequestAccess.view",
            "controlId": "fcl",
            "transition": "slide",
            "bypassed": {}
        },
        "routes": [{
            "pattern": "jobprofile",
            "name": "jobprofile",
            "target": [
                "JobProfileSelector",
                "JobProfileOrder"
            ]
        }, {
            "pattern": ":layout:",
            "name": "authorize",
            "target": [
                "Authorization"
            ]
        }],
        "targets": {
            "Authorization": {
                "viewName": "Authorization",
                "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages"
            },
            "JobProfileOrder": {
                "viewName": "JobProfileOrder",
                "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages"
            },
            "JobProfileSelector": {
                "viewName": "JobProfileSelector",
                "controlAggregation": "beginColumnPages"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

when I do the call

```
var oRouter = this._getRouter();
oRouter.navTo("jobprofile");
```

it shows one column layout instead two columns. I expect to be two columns, because I have defined:

```
"pattern": "jobprofile",
"name": "jobprofile",
"target": [
    "JobProfileSelector",
    "JobProfileOrder"
]
```

Two targets for the path `/jobprofile`.
I expect, that the app should show like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have created an example app https://github.com/softshipper/fclpoc.
Click on `Go to jobprofile`

[image]

and you will redirect to page `/jobprofile` path. Here I expect, that it is going to show me **Second** and **Third** view next to each other, like master detail view.

Comment: Have a look at the answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390737/why-the-navigation-to-twocolumnsmidexpanded-does-not-work

Comment: I have tried it but I do not know, what exactly I have to do. Could you please make a pull request on the github?

Comment: if you start off the example that I referred to in the other question, you could remove unnecessary stuff bit by bit to learn. the example is not very large. first - drop the content of all the columns and replace them by "hello world left", "hello world middle" "and hello world right"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the navigation to TwoColumnsMidExpanded does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390737/why-the-navigation-to-twocolumnsmidexpanded-does-not-work)

Comment: I have tried to whole day. However i will try it again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust property `layout` of your `FlexibleColumnLayout` in order to have 1, 2 or 3 columns. Default is 1.

In your root view, you already have a binding on this property, which is a good idea.

```
<FlexibleColumnLayout id="fcl"
                stateChange="onStateChanged"
                layout="{/layout}"
                backgroundDesign="Solid">
            </FlexibleColumnLayout>
```

However, you are not calling function `_updateLayout` from the `App.controller.js` anywhere.

I suggest refactoring this controller to adjust the layout based on the active route.

Comment: I do not know, what exactly I have to do. Could you please make a pull request on the github?

Comment: You have to adjust property layout of your FlexibleColumnLayout in order to have 1, 2 or 3 columns. Default is 1.